# Installing Packages in Sitecore PaaS/WebApp

Tags: azure, paas, packages

Sitecore Support has stated that I can’t install packages like PowerShell Extensions and SXA if my PaaS environment is already deployed. They stated I need to redeploy and add these to the ARM Templates.

As this is an existing Prod environment, why can’t I just deploy to the CMS/install packages like IaaS. I am sure there are some differences as the CMS WebApp is in a separate AppService than other roles.

In essence, what are the differences and proper method for deploying packages like PowerShell Extensions and SXA to a Sitecore PaaS 9.0 XP1 Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficult answer is: it depends... on how you do your deployments.

Normally on PAAS you will deploy the full application (Sitecore + packages + your own code) which means indeed that you need to add the packages to the ARM templates.

If you already have provisioned your environment and don't want to do this again, you need to install the packages once throught the Sitecore installation wizard as you normally would in an IAAS setup to get the items from the package in your databases.

But as stated, if you redeploy the entire application (which is done mostly) you need to have the packages in the ARM templates (no-database-version) as well or they will be gone.

And as Jason added correctly, installing the files to the CD environments will be difficult..  that will be much easier with a deploy (with adapted ARM templates).

Comment: I believe the CDs are also hardened so that you cannot install the files needed for some packages onto the CD? I cannot recall at the moment...

Comment: Indeed.. good comment!

Comment: So since I have already deployed, there are no differences to installing packages... but to Jason’s comment, are there special steps as it’s PaaS as I can’t redeploy?

Comment: You need to do both. Install the packages once to update the databases. And add the no-db versions to your ARM templates for re-deployment (for CM and CD).

Comment: I can’t redeploy though... as in I don’t redeploy the WebApps, only push code to them. I view the ARM templates as redeploying the WebApp itself, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. And I would reconsider your deployment process..  ;)

Comment: I am unable to as who controls my WebApps has an SLA that doesn’t allow me to redeploy... so the core question is, can and how do I deploy packages given this constraint? Thanks for all the guidance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95767/discussion-between-gatogordo-and-kode).